# Operating System not found when loading DD image in VMware

Tags: linux, boot, vmware-workstation, disk-image

I provide much details below to hopefully make my issue as clear as possible.

Using `dd if=/dev/ps3da2 of=/mnt/edexhdd/EDPS3LINUX.iso bs=16384` I copied a fairly huge partition from a physical Linux non-Xwindow installation on a PPC64 architecture (actually the PS3) to an external HDD. The partition which on Linux was one of the two present (i.e. /boot and /) is more than 66 GB. This partition was the second and not bootable. Actually `fdisk -lu /mnt/edexhdd/EDPS3LINUX.iso` says something like this partition 'has no valid partition table'.

Meanwhile I can mount it on Linux via `mount -o loop /mnt/edexhdd/EDPS3LINUX.iso /mnt/testmnt` and walk through it all.

My intention is to work from a VMWare Workstation on my Windows 7 laptop (64 bit and VT capable). Everything is duly installed and other VMWare images work well. So I moved the image to Windows and created the necessary vmdk file...

```
D:\raw2vmdk>java -jar raw2vmdk.jar EDPS3LINUX.iso EDPS3LINUX.vmdk

Analysing image: D:\EDPS3LINUX.iso [66229960704 bytes]

Number of sectors:      129355392
Number of cylinders:    0
Heads per track:        0
Sectors per track:      0

Loading VMDK template...
Writing VMDK file to: D:\EDPS3LINUX.vmdk
All done.
```

Finally I walk through the usual steps in VMWare Workstation (8) to load my image (pointing to `C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware Workstation\linux.iso` for the CD/DVD ISO and `D:\EDPS3LINUX.vmdk` for the HDD image). After which all I see is the network boot PXE stuff and then everything halts with 'operating system not found'.

Under my circumstances what can I do to boot my PS3 image in VMWare as intended? I don't imagine reinstalling all the Linux stuff into the VMWare environment - way too much stuff and configs done. Pls help.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to boot a partition  that is for ppc64 architecture on an x86 machine...

Comment: What you are trying to do is not possible.